# bootstrap css isn't rendering properly inside body

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4

For some reason my bootstrap css is not rendering the content in the body of my page correctly. The paragraph tag is rendering inside the image tag. The paragraph tag and image tag are both inside the body.

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Paul Drake's Website</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-grid.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/site.css">
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-3">
                <a href="files/Resume 2020.pdf">Resume</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 text-center">
                <h1>Paul Drake's Website</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropDownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="False">My Projects</button>
                <div class="dropdown-menu col-3" aria-labelledby="dropDownMenuButton">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" asp-controller="Movie" asp-action="GetMovies">Streaming Movie App</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
<main>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <IMG src="files/_DSC0630-Costco3.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Gravida cum sociis natoque penatibus. Leo vel fringilla est ullamcorper eget nulla facilisi etiam dignissim. Diam sit amet nisl suscipit adipiscing bibendum. Diam sollicitudin tempor id eu nisl. Lacus vel facilisis volutpat est velit egestas. Purus gravida quis blandit turpis cursus in hac habitasse platea. Non enim praesent elementum facilisis leo vel. Nunc scelerisque viverra mauris in aliquam sem fringilla ut. Tristique sollicitudin nibh sit amet commodo. Porta nibh venenatis cras sed felis eget. Sapien nec sagittis aliquam malesuada bibendum arcu vitae. Enim eu turpis egestas pretium aenean pharetra magna ac. Ac auctor augue mauris augue neque gravida in fermentum et. Turpis egestas maecenas pharetra convallis posuere morbi leo urna molestie. Tristique sollicitudin nibh sit amet. Laoreet sit amet cursus sit amet dictum sit. Sit amet tellus cras adipiscing enim. Ut eu sem integer vitae justo eget magna.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm trying to use the bootstrap css files that rider includes in the asp.net mvc templete. So I would like to not use a cdn if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I have replicated your issue in codepen.io and found out that you are missing a cdn link in your head section, add the following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
```